# Algorithm design for laravel services to an IOS App

Tags: php, ios, api, laravel-routing, laravel-5.3

I used to work on codeignitor for mobile app services but now i am instructed to use Laravel instead of codeignitor.

in codeignitor we can call a controller (API in my case)   directly from a url so with we can send some data . but in Laravel we can not call a controller directly from URL so we have to use routes to call a controller. 
So how would a mobile App would call and send data to a route then the route would call the corresponding service of the API.

i am new to laravel so any help will a massive help.

Thank You .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These work the same as the would work on php or codeignitor .

**POST method.**
in native php and codeignitor you get the input field by specifying POST method.However in Laravel You have to specify that in route .
I hope you have some idea of MVC .You will specify your post route like that....

```
 Route::post('/login', 'Api@Signin');
```

Here is a simple service which logs in the user.

```
public function Signin()
{
     $validation = Validator::make(Request::all(),[ 
        'email'        => 'required',
        'password'     => 'required',
        'device_type'  => 'required',
        'device_token' => 'required',

    ]);


    if($validation->fails())
     {

            $finalResult = array('code' => 100,
                'msg' => 'Data Entered Not Correct.',
                'data' => array()
                );

     }

   else
     {
           $login = User::where(
                [
                    ['email', '=', Input::get('email')],
                    ['password', '=', md5(Input::get('password'))],
                ])->first();



           if (is_null($login))
        {

            $finalResult = array('code' => 100,
                'msg' => 'Your Account Does not exist.',
                'data' => array()
                );

        }

        else
        {


            $user= User::where('email', '=', Input::get('email'))->first();
                $user->device_token = Input::get('device_token');
                $user->device_type = Input::get('device_type');

                $user->save();


            $data = User::where(
                 [ 'email'    =>Input::get('email')],
                 [ 'password' =>md5(Input::get('password'))]
                 )->get();


            $finalResult = array('code' => 200,
                'msg' => 'Success',
                'data' => $data
                );

        }

    }   

        echo json_encode($finalResult);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create resourceful controller for an API, run `php artisan make:controller PhotoController` it will generate all basic CRUD operations for your resource (here Photo). Now in your `routes.php` file you will see can add `Route::resource('photo', 'PhotoController');` which will generate all routes for you. You can see list of all route by running `php artisan route:list`. reference : https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/controllers#restful-resource-controllers

In your controller methods you do same stuff as you used to do in Codeignitor. You can call get/post route from IOS with proper parameters and it will do thing for you.

**Edit:**
In your controller method you can get data sent like this :

```
    public function someFunction(Request $request){
    $data = $request->get('some_key_sent_from_device');
}
```

Comment: Thank you Nitesh for you help .please also help me on this that

Comment: When an IOS user hits a URL and also sends some data with it 
how will the route get the sent data and then send it to the controller method ?

Comment: Its pretty simple Nomi. You pass `Request` object in controller method as parameter. This Request object has all data. Modified my answer for that.